# C# - Identity Framework and integer UserId - await SignInAsync issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, asp.net-identity

I am working on an MVC5 demo app and attempting to make us of the Identity Framework, in conjunction with Dapper within this.

I have implemented a n-tier hybrid architecture with many layers including the DAL handled by Dapper (with repository pattern). I am using the standard `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity` with both Owin and Core assemblies correctly referenced for authentication - I read on SO that rolling your own is not advisable!

I digress, the problem I am having is with the following method within my Identity implementation...

```
PasswordSignInAsync()
```

For example, within my `AccountContoller.cs` I have the following:

```
 // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);

        int userId = Int32.Parse(User.Identity.GetUserId());

        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                ViewBag.UserId = userId;
                return RedirectToAction("Index",  new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "User", action = "Index", id = userId }));
                //return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
                return View(model);
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Basically, the method logs users in and if `SignInStatus.Success` then redirects to my `UserController.cs` Index method. The Index method accepts an integer id - aka the UserId variable of the authenticated user.

My `Index(int id)` routes to /Users/{id} or for example /Users/5

However, what happens after submitting the form is:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: String    Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be
>   null. Parameter name: String
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 77:             var result = await
>   SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password,
>   model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false); Line 78:  Line 79:
>   int userId = Int32.Parse(User.Identity.GetUserId()); Line 80:
>   Line 81:             switch (result)
>
> Source File: 
>   c:[ProjectName is omitted]\Controllers\AccountController.cs
>   Line:  79
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: String] 
>   System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options,
>   NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
>   +12099581
>   System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) 
>   +120
>   System.Int32.Parse(String s) +24 [ProjectName is omitted for security].Controllers.
>   d__4.MoveNext() in
>   [ProjectName is omitted]\Controllers\AccountController.cs:79
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +58    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   +26    System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.ThrowIfFaulted(Task task)
>   +61    System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +114
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.b__36(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +66
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +47
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +102
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()
>   +117    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>   +323    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +47
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +102
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +50
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c()
>   +72    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +185
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +42
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +56
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +40
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +34
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +70
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +56
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +37
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__15(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, Controller controller) +39
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +62
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +56
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +37    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +39
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +39
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +39
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +70
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +56
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +37
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +40    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +38
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +9723757    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

I do not want my Index action within the `UserController` to accept nullable params (i.e. int? id) although making the int nullable would fix it (by loading blank index page) - but the whole point is a Profile belongs to a user and cannot be generic...

```
    // UserController.cs  /User/Index/5
    // GET: User's Profile page by calling DAL ProfileRepository.cs!
    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        Profile profile = _profileRepository.ProfileGet(id);
        return View(profile);
    }
```

Strange thing is, if I reload the login page and resubmit the login form it manages to assign an integer value to the userId variable and route to their Profile!

I don't know if it is something to do with the await SignInAsync method but surely this should stop the thread executing until the method call is complete?

Or perhaps it's to do with the parsing of the string into an int here:
`int userId = Int32.Parse(User.Identity.GetUserId());`

but if the `SignInAsync` has finished successfully there should be a `User.Identity` to call `GetUserId()` on right?

So it is strange therefore that Ctrl + F5 after the error dump appearing would then cause the correct Profile page to load - meaning the integer value is correctly assigned.

Bah! I'm at the point where I am considering scrapping the Identity framework - it was tough enough for me decouple it from the horrid EF and use my own DB schema!

If you guys need to see anymore of my source please let me know

All the best,

:-)

or should it be o.O !

Comment: To avoid confusion, GUID has been exorcised from Indentity in my source with <int> in its place. Moreover, Profiles (aka /User/5) are public very much in the same manner as Twitter Urls. Profile data is non-sensitive and de-coupled from Indentity and User logins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have some issue in your code. First Identity's default user id value is GUID so you can't parse to int. Keep using string data type or change default data type to int. Second you are using `User.Identity.GetUserId()` just after calling `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync()` method. Don't work. At last one new request must send to server so you could check signed in user info. This is why your code works after a refresh. Third your index action has security issue, everyone could access your users data by directly typing proper URL in his browser. Therefore you could write something like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, 
        model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);

    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            ViewBag.UserId = userId;
            return RedirectToAction("Index","User");
        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
            return View("Lockout");
        case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
            return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
        case SignInStatus.Failure:
            return View(model);
        default:
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
            return View(model);
    }
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    string userID=User.Identity.GetUserId();
    // use userID in your way
}
```

But if you want to get user id just before calling `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync()` without redirecting consider using user manager to get user id:

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, 
        model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);

var userId =UserManager.FindByName(model.UserName).Id;
// instead of 
// int userId = Int32.Parse(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

Comment: Hi Sam - many thanks for your response. Actually it's a social app so I want people to type the URL into their browser. Profiles are public... Login credentials aka UserId PasswordHash etc are stored in an entirely separate DB. The Profile data obtained via repository call is non-sensitive i.e. avatar, description, profile bg etc.  A bit like Twitter :-) Moreover, I have exorcised any GUID from Identity and changed user model type to User<int>. However, thanks for taking the time to give pointers and code :)

Comment: Ok if so we don't have any security concern and `int` to `string` issue. But the second statement still true. you need at last one redirect to sing in takes effect and you could get user id. Or use user manager to get user id. See updated post.

Comment: Brilliant thanks mate - that make perfect sense and works! Voted up :)